# Python - cannot install spaCy

Tags: python-2.7, installation, spacy

I am trying to install spaCy on a Mac (OSX El Capitain). I am running python 2.7, have pip 18.0 and setuptools 40.0.

Whenever I run 'sudo pip install spacy', I get the following:

```
Installing collected packages: numpy, murmurhash, cymem, preshed, msgpack, msgpack-numpy, toolz, cytoolz, wrapt, plac, tqdm, six, dill, pathlib, thinc, ujson, regex, idna, urllib3, chardet, certifi, requests, spacy
Running setup.py install for murmurhash ... done
Running setup.py install for preshed ... done
Running setup.py install for msgpack ... done
Running setup.py install for toolz ... done
Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... done
Running setup.py install for wrapt ... done

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/man'
```

So, there must be something in the plac package that it doesn't like. The file in the above path doesn't exist.

Has anyone else found a solution to this?

Comment: This is strange – it likely has a problem with [this line and syntax](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/setup.py#L199), but this shouldn't actually be a problem if you're using a recent version of pip and setuptools. Would you mind [opening an issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues) on the issue tracker with your environment info?

Comment: @Ines - it turns out that when I updated setuptools with pip, it told me it was installing v40.0, but did't actually do so. I used homebrew to update it and that worked correctly. However, now getting a different error - I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's definitely good that this came up, because it turns out the requirements syntax potentially causes some other problems and is not always handled correctly by `setuptools`... About the other error: It's possible that this is a side-effect of running `pip install` with `sudo`. Does it work without it? You can also add `--user` to `pip install` to make sure you're installing to a user directory and not to your system Python.

Comment: @Ines - that was perfect. Adding --user to the install worked! Many thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @Ines - where does it put the files if you install in the user directory? I cannot find the spacy files.

Comment: You can always run the following command to find the path to your spaCy installation: `python -c "import spacy; print(spacy.__file__)"`. Btw, if you've installed spaCy with `--user`, make sure to also download the models with `--user`, so pip puts them in the correct place.

Comment: @Ines - when I run the script, it cannot find spacy and triggers an error. Do I need to add anything to a path so it can see it?